# Using pyqtSignal in emitting signal for maptool in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

For QGIS I have a plugin named GGAImporter:

```
from .point_tool import PointTool
class GGAImporter:
...
    def addFachdatum(self):
        self.mapTool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.beforeMapTool=self.iface.mapCanvas().mapTool()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.mapTool)
        self.mapTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.onMapClick)
    
    def onMapClick(point):
        logging.warning('onMapClick: '+point.asWkt())
```

In a several file point_tool.py there is the class for the tool:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool, QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsMessageLog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class PointTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint): 
    canvasClicked = pyqtSignal('QgsPointXY')
    
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super(QgsMapTool, self).__init__(canvas)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point_canvas_crs = event.mapPoint()

        self.canvasClicked.emit(point_canvas_crs)
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('canvasReleaseEvent '+point_canvas_crs.asWkt())
```

The logmessage from point_tool is correctly:

```
2021-11-19T09:51:29     WARNING    canvasReleaseEvent POINT(646484.461160849314183 5857199.37299698870629072)
```

But in GGAImporter-class I get an error:

```
2021-11-19T09:51:29     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/sschmidt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\gga_importer\gga_importer.py", line 427, in onMapClick
              logging.warning('onMapClick: '+point.asWkt())
             AttributeError: 'GGAImporter' object has no attribute 'asWkt'
```

It seems that the parameter of type **QgsPointXY** by emitting to slot get lost and is then my main-class of the plugin. Is there an error with **PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal**?

Comment: You forgot to add `self` as the first argument of your `onMapClick()` method. It should be: `def onMapClick(self, point):`. The class instance object needs to be the first argument of all class methods.

Comment: I'm so blind. Thank you. Put your text in an answer, then I can accept it ;)

Comment: No problem, done :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot to add `self` as the first argument of your `onMapClick()` method. The class instance object needs to be the first argument of all class methods. The `canvasClicked()` signal also emits the `Qt.MouseButton` object which caused the event which you can also catch.

Your slot method definition should look like:

```py
def onMapClick(self, point, button):
    logging.warning('onMapClick: '+point.asWkt())
```